# Crowdfunding without the funding

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that is basically like crowdfunding/crowdfunded, except it's not about funding specifically and instead can mean any activity that involves a large group. Example: how would you describe Wikipedia? Crowd... written? Crowdproject? Obviously those aren't real words, those are just examples of what I'm looking for.

You have a sentence like this:
*Kickstarter is a crowdfunding platform.*

and I need something like this:
*Wikipedia is a **(adjective that implies it is written/contributed to by a large group of people)** website.*

Comment: I think this will be reopened if you make the following changes: add a sample sentence (cuz of site rules), remove the word "catchy" (as it might be the reason for the opinion-based vote(s)),  and clarify the point that you're looking for a word to describe "work done by an external group" (if you want the question to be extra clear). I actually disagree with needing to add research here, since you presumably already know that your suggestions (e.g. crowdwritten) are not real words, so looking for synonyms of them (or crowdfunding even) is a fruitless exercise.

Comment: @Laurel Made some changes, hopefully it will appease the stickler gods. Sidenote: it doesn't have to be an external group. It just kinda goes without saying that it's mostly an external group because of its nature as a group project, where everyone can contribute - mostly strangers.

Comment: Are you asking, like marketing, to come up with a new word that sounds like it means this, or are you trying to remember a word you've heard before that you're pretty sure already captures this?

Comment: @Mitch I'm looking (or was looking, as I found my answer) for an already existing word. Otherwise, I think I'd be in the wrong place to ask for a new made-up word.

Comment: @noClue OK. The generally used existing word is 'crowdsource' (as both the answers have given). It was of course a neologism probably around the time Wikipedia became known for it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Crowdsourcing**:

> Crowdsourcing is a sourcing model in which individuals or organizations obtain goods and services, including ideas and finances, from a large, relatively open and often rapidly-evolving group of internet users; it divides work between participants to achieve a cumulative result.
>
> [...]
>
> It has also been used by not-for-profit organizations and to create common goods (e.g. Wikipedia).
> <sub>[Wikipedia: Crowdsourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing)</sub>

Answer (score 14):

**crowdsourcing**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crowdsourcing)

> A method of outsourcing any work over the internet or similar network
>   by appealing to people(s) to contribute to the project independently
>   or as a collaboration.